# Reading multiple text lines from a file as stream

Tags: .net, powershell, scripting

I need to read and process very large text file in powershell  which I am able to do using the following pattern. However reading line by line seems inefficient to me.

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($file)
while(!$reader.EndOfStream){
 $line = $reader.ReadLine()
 ###Do something
}
```

so instead of reading line by line, is it possible to read multiple lines in one go from some kind of stream object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the built-in command for this:

```
Get-Content $file -ReadCount 1024 | Foreach {$_} | Where {$_ -match 'pattern'}
```

This reads 1024 lines at a time.  Run those through a Foreach command to flatten the array of 1024 lines into single lines for processing - in this case, filtering based on a regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are already reading from "some kind of stream object", using a stream reader.
It depends on what you want to do. If you want to process things on a line-by-line basis (e.g. if you want to see if a line contains a certain word), then what you're doing is pretty much the right way.
You could read more data at once, using the StreamReader.Read method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.110).aspx
You could also read all of it at once, using ReadAll.
All depends on what level you want to parse things.